# When converting csv to xls in a formatted template why is the first sheet not formatted?

Tags: c#, excel, csv, interop, xls

Building an application that reads a CSV file and converts it into xls with c# in VS 2017.

I'm using CsvHelper and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to accomplish this.

The application can read a CSV file in a windows form, have the program set up a template and insert into that formatted template all the values in the correct cells HOWEVER the very first page created no matter which file is used is not formatted and gets inserted in a un-formatted excel page.

I have attempted:

1. changing the arguments of the "Workbook.Sheets.Add"
2. where in the logic the sheets get added
3. changing the arguments in the SaveAs function
4. Changing various indexes from 1 to 0 and visa versa

I am new to working with the (Interop.Excel) namespace and have spent much time reading the DOCS on the MS web-page yet I still cannot resolve this issue.

Here is how I am adding the pages to the workbook:

```
if (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / pageCount);
                            Thread.Sleep(delay);
                            wb.Sheets.Add(missing,After:wb.Sheets[wb.Sheets.Count],Count:missing,Type:template);
                            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Sheets[wb.Sheets.Count];
                        }
```

Here is how I am saving the pages:

```c#
wb.SaveAs(fileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, missing, missing, true, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                        XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges,
                        missing, missing);
                    excel.Quit();
```

Here is a reference to the whole method:

```c#
namespace csvReader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        struct DataParameter
        {
            public List<material> materialList;
            public List<material> smallMats;
            public Workbook wbData;
            public string Filename { get; set; }
            public int Delay;
        }

        DataParameter _inputParameter;
private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
                return;
            using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls" })
            {
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    _inputParameter.Filename = sfd.FileName;
                    _inputParameter.materialList = materialBindingSource2.DataSource as List<material>;
                    _inputParameter.Delay = 100;
                    progressBar.Minimum = 0;
                    progressBar.Value = 0;


                    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(_inputParameter);
                }
            }
        }
 private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            object missing = Type.Missing;
            List<material> list = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).materialList;
            List<material> cellM = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).smallMats;
            string fileName = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).Filename;
            int pageCount = 1;
            int process = list.Count;
            int setRows = 19;
            int delay = 100;

            if (list.Count > setRows)
            {
                pageCount = process / setRows;
            }
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            string template = "(mytemplatefilepath)";
            Workbook wb = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).wbData;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();
            excel.Visible = false;

            int index = 1;

            try
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < pageCount; i++)
                {
                    if (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / pageCount);
                        Thread.Sleep(delay);
                        wb.Sheets.Add(missing,After:wb.Sheets[wb.Sheets.Count],Count:missing,Type:template);
                        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Sheets[wb.Sheets.Count];
                    }
                }

                int range = 1;
                int sheetIndex = 1;


                foreach (Worksheet w in wb.Sheets)
                {                    
                    w.Name = "Sheet" + sheetIndex++;
                    //w.Cells["L", 3] = tbSpecial.Text;
                    cellM = list.GetRange(range, 19);
                    int startCell = 7;
                    foreach (material m in cellM)
                    {
                        if (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                        {

                            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process);
                            Thread.Sleep(delay);
                            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range newInput = w.get_Range("C" + startCell, "L" + startCell) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range;                           
                            w.Cells[startCell, 2] = m.Qty.ToString();
                            w.Cells[startCell, 3] = m.Section.ToString();
                            w.Cells[startCell, 4] = m.Length.ToString();
                            w.Cells[startCell, 5] = m.Camber.ToString();
                            w.Cells[startCell, 6] = m.Ends.ToString();
                            w.Cells[startCell, 7] = m.Grade.ToString();
                            w.Cells[startCell, 8] = m.Seq.ToString();
                            w.Cells[startCell, 9] = m.Member.ToString();
                            //w.Cells["L", 3] ="700";
                            startCell++;
                        }
                    }
                    range = range + 19;
                }
                wb.SaveAs(fileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, missing, missing, true, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                    XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges,
                    missing, missing);
                excel.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Here is the first page of a data set of 203 pages

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PHRR.jpg

and the other 202 pages appear as so

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbniN.jpg

I feel like it's syntax error I'm making somewhere. 
Although it is easy to fill in one excel page I'd rather have the program complete 100% of this work with the technologies I am using.

Comment: Am I correct in seeing you set the sheet page to 1? Shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: @gilliduck if you're referring to `w.Name =  sheetIndex++.ToString();` then this simply names the page. It doesn't refer to the index. All the pages should be getting iterated in the foreach loop. Or were you talking about `wb.Sheets.Add(missing,After:wb.Sheets[wb.Sheets.Count],Count:missing,Type:template);` where I feel that I'm doing the indexing incorrectly?

Comment: There is a lot to deconstruct in there and I'm missing most of the context for it, but gut reaction is it's related to the fact that you use 1 all over the place instead of 0 for your starting count of things. `Index`, `i`, `range`, `sheetIndex`. Not sure which, if any, are the cause, but I'd put (small) money that that's your issue.

Comment: That's reasonable @gilliduck and three templates are getting made however if i is changed to 0 in the first FOR loop the program breaks https://imgur.com/Y1E3Zd8. This is why I feel these pages need to be added in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the first sheet did not have the template layout and that if 'i = 0' bombs is that by default when instantiating a workbook with Workbooks.Add() a new Worksheet is added. This sheet will not be formatted however a template can be added in the parenthesis of the Add method to give that first sheet that format.

```
string template = "C:/whereEverMyTemplateIs/template"
 wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(template);
```

Then just remember that it is added and make as many more as needed

```
for (int i = 1; i < pageCount; i++)
                {
                    if (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / pageCount);
                        Thread.Sleep(delay);
                        wb.Sheets.Add(missing,After:wb.Sheets[wb.Sheets.Count],Count:missing,
Type:template);
                        //Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Sheets[wb.Sheets.Count];
                    }
                }
```